# Spring framework security bean "AuthenticationManager" not found

Tags: spring-boot, spring-mvc, spring-security, oauth-2.0, spring-security-oauth2

I am using OAuth2 with spring boot. I am new to Oauth. I am getting this **Consider defining a bean of type 'org.springframework.security.authentication.AuthenticationManager' in your configuration** exception while running my spring boot application. I have seen some other answered questions in StackOverflow but they were no fulfilling my need. I am using Spring boot version **2.3.3.RELEASE**. I am taking reference from this  [Repository](https://github.com/TechPrimers/spring-security-oauth-example). I have just Updated the Version of my application. Here is my class where i am facing this issue:

```
import org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.Autowired;
import org.springframework.context.annotation.Configuration;
import org.springframework.security.authentication.AuthenticationManager;
import org.springframework.security.oauth2.config.annotation.configurers.ClientDetailsServiceConfigurer;
import org.springframework.security.oauth2.config.annotation.web.configuration.AuthorizationServerConfigurerAdapter;
import org.springframework.security.oauth2.config.annotation.web.configuration.EnableAuthorizationServer;
import org.springframework.security.oauth2.config.annotation.web.configurers.AuthorizationServerEndpointsConfigurer;
import org.springframework.security.oauth2.config.annotation.web.configurers.AuthorizationServerSecurityConfigurer;

@EnableAuthorizationServer
@Configuration
public class AuthorizationServerConfig extends AuthorizationServerConfigurerAdapter {

    @Autowired
    private AuthenticationManager authenticationManager;

    @Override
    public void configure(AuthorizationServerSecurityConfigurer security) throws Exception {

        security.tokenKeyAccess("permitAll()").checkTokenAccess("isAuthenticated()");
    }

    @Override
    public void configure(ClientDetailsServiceConfigurer clients) throws Exception {
        clients.inMemory().withClient("ClientId").secret("secret").authorizedGrantTypes("authorization_code")
                .scopes("user_info").autoApprove(true);
    }

    @Override
    public void configure(AuthorizationServerEndpointsConfigurer endpoints) throws Exception {

        endpoints.authenticationManager(authenticationManager);
    }
}
```

If I create a bean like this. :

```
@Bean
public AuthenticationManager authenticationManagerBean() throws Exception {
    return super.authenticationManagerBean();
}
```

it has resolved my error for a class that extends WebSecurityConfigurerAdapter but my other class extends AuthorizationServerConfigurerAdapter and for this class, the solution is not working
and I am getting a warning saying **The method authenticationManagerBean() is undefined for the type AuthorizationServerConfigurerAdapter**. Could you please help me.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I have resolved this issue by just updating my AuthorizationServerConfig.java class & ResourceServerConfig.java class like this:

**AuthorizationServerConfig.java class:**

```
package com.ab.security.config;

import org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.Autowired;
import org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.Qualifier;
import org.springframework.context.annotation.Configuration;
import org.springframework.security.authentication.AuthenticationManager;
import org.springframework.security.oauth2.config.annotation.configurers.ClientDetailsServiceConfigurer;
import org.springframework.security.oauth2.config.annotation.web.configuration.AuthorizationServerConfigurerAdapter;
import org.springframework.security.oauth2.config.annotation.web.configuration.EnableAuthorizationServer;
import org.springframework.security.oauth2.config.annotation.web.configurers.AuthorizationServerEndpointsConfigurer;
import org.springframework.security.oauth2.config.annotation.web.configurers.AuthorizationServerSecurityConfigurer;

@EnableAuthorizationServer
@Configuration
public class AuthorizationServerConfig extends AuthorizationServerConfigurerAdapter {

    @Autowired
    @Qualifier("authenticationManagerBean")
    private AuthenticationManager authenticationManager;

    @Override
    public void configure(AuthorizationServerSecurityConfigurer security) throws Exception {

        security.tokenKeyAccess("permitAll()").checkTokenAccess("isAuthenticated()");
    }

    @Override
    public void configure(ClientDetailsServiceConfigurer clients) throws Exception {
        clients.inMemory().withClient("ClientId").secret("secret").authorizedGrantTypes("authorization_code")
                .scopes("user_info").autoApprove(true);
    }

    @Override
    public void configure(AuthorizationServerEndpointsConfigurer endpoints) throws Exception {

        endpoints.authenticationManager(authenticationManager);
    }
    
}
```

**ResourceServerConfig.java class:**

```
package com.ab.security.config;

import org.springframework.context.annotation.Bean;
import org.springframework.context.annotation.Configuration;
import org.springframework.security.authentication.AuthenticationManager;
import org.springframework.security.config.annotation.authentication.builders.AuthenticationManagerBuilder;
import org.springframework.security.config.annotation.web.builders.HttpSecurity;
import org.springframework.security.config.annotation.web.configuration.WebSecurityConfigurerAdapter;
import org.springframework.security.oauth2.config.annotation.web.configuration.EnableResourceServer;

@EnableResourceServer
@Configuration
public class ResourceServerConfig extends WebSecurityConfigurerAdapter {

    @Override
    protected void configure(HttpSecurity http) throws Exception {
        http.requestMatchers().antMatchers("/login", "/oauth/authorize").and().authorizeRequests().anyRequest()
                .authenticated().and().formLogin().permitAll();
    }

    @Override
    protected void configure(AuthenticationManagerBuilder auth) throws Exception {

        auth.parentAuthenticationManager(authenticationManagerBean()).inMemoryAuthentication().withUser("Peter")
                .password("peter").roles("USER");
    }

    @Override
    @Bean
    public AuthenticationManager authenticationManagerBean() throws Exception {
        return super.authenticationManagerBean();
    }

}
```

Answer (score 0):

You are overriding a method that does not exist in `AuthorizationServerConfigurerAdapter` hense the error.

As you can see `AuthorizationServerConfigurerAdapter` define only `configure` method with 3 signatures:

```
public class AuthorizationServerConfigurerAdapter implements AuthorizationServerConfigurer {

    @Override
    public void configure(AuthorizationServerSecurityConfigurer security) throws Exception {
    }

    @Override
    public void configure(ClientDetailsServiceConfigurer clients) throws Exception {
    }

    @Override
    public void configure(AuthorizationServerEndpointsConfigurer endpoints) throws Exception {
    }

}
```

Comment: These 3 methods only have an override. I didn't understand what you want to say. Could you please look into the class again.

Comment: authenticationManagerBean method is defined in WebSecurityConfigurerAdapter 
 but not in AuthorizationServerConfigurerAdapter nor in AuthorizationServerConfigurer. @Override overrides an existing method from inherited Class or implemented Interface.

Comment: You have to remove @Override from AuthenticationManager bean definition

Comment: Even if i delete @Override  annotation, it is not resolving my problem. In last couple of lines of my question i have described the warning which i am getting is still not resolved.